# How to list EKS PODS from AWS lambda SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-lambda, amazon-eks

Good day!

Is there any way to list the eks pods of a specific namespace from AWS lambda python using SDK?.

(Alternative of kubectl get pods -n namespace)

I tried searching in the following documentation. But I could not find. Any better idea?

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/eks.html

Thanks in advance

Comment: `kubectl` is just a command-line interface to the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/); can you use a Python [client library](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) to interface with Kubernetes (this is not EKS/AWS-specific)?